# Cannot display texture with SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Im trying to display a texture with SDL2.

[image: 16x20]

Here is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

#include "Texture.h"

SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;
SDL_Event e;

Texture texture(renderer, "assets/player.png", 16, 20); // this the texture is defined
SDL_Texture* t;
bool running = true;

void update();
void draw();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("My Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    while (running) {
        update();
        draw();
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

void update() {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            running = false;
        }
    }
}

void draw() {
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    texture.show(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Texture.cpp

```
#include "Texture.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <string>

Texture::Texture(SDL_Renderer*& renderer, std::string path, int w, int h) {
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

    SDL_Surface* temp_surface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, temp_surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(temp_surface);
    d_rect.w = w;
    d_rect.h = h;
}

void Texture::show(SDL_Renderer*& renderer) {
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &d_rect);
}
```

Texture.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <string>

class Texture {
    public:
        Texture(SDL_Renderer*& renderer, std::string path, int w, int h);
        void show(SDL_Renderer*& renderer);

        SDL_Texture* texture;
        SDL_Rect d_rect;
        SDL_Renderer* renderer;
};
```

Here is my file structure:\

```
src/\
...main.cpp\
...Texture.cpp\
...Texture.h\
assets/\
...player.png
```

I'm pretty new to C++ and ive been following some tutorials so I don't really know Whats going on
I've been following https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL SDL tutorials but this is the part I'm getting stuck on

Comment: Your class does not make much sense. `Texture::Texture(SDL_Renderer*&, ...` shadows the global `SDL_Renderer* renderer;` from `main()`. Your constructor doesn't actually set the member `renderer`. `SDL_Texture* t;` is declared but not used.  `texture.show()` isn't called, etc.. Maybe you should have another look at what you are trying to accomplish compared to [Lesson 07 Texture Loading and Rendering](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/07_texture_loading_and_rendering/index.php)

Comment: @David C. Rankin There are many things in this code that I forgot to remove such as the renderer member in my class. The `SDL_Texture* t` was for testing how most of the tutorials I saw did displaying textures, which didn't work. `texture.show()` is called in the draw function.

As for the as for the `Texture::Texture(SDL_Renderer*&` and all that, I'm not very familiar with pointers and such so the way I did it makes more sense to me, which is a probably also why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `Texture::Texture` happens at program startup time, before `main`. Therefore, that code sees a nullpointer for `renderer`. That very probably makes your call to `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` fail.

Move the initialization of your `texture` object inside `main`, after `renderer` is created:

```
// at top-level:
Texture *texture;

int main () {
    // ...
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    texture = new Texture(renderer, "assets/player.png", 16, 20);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I'm not too familiar with new in c++ so I avoided using it. I can still draw things like rectangles and stuff, but for some reason not textures. Not sure what I'm doing wrong tbh, although I'm sure its something stupid.